# Fonts are not rendered in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, webkit, font-face

Our customers don`t see any font on our site. The font is loaded from our server (.woff, .ttf, .eot, .svg), font name - Lato Sans. In styles is noted that if font is unavailable, you should use Arial, or any other system sans-serif font. Also in styles is noted font smoothing, here is an example from the code:

```css
font-family: "Lato Sans", "PT Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
font-smooth: always;
text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
```

An example of loading for one of other fonts:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato Sans';
    src: url('/Content/webfonts/LatoSans/lato-regular.eot');
    src: url('/Content/webfonts/LatoSans/lato-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/Content/webfonts/LatoSans/lato-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/Content/webfonts/LatoSans/lato-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Description: The client visits the site (Google Chrome 58, Windows), but does not see any text. All the graphics rendered, and the font doesn`t. The text is not shown by the system font either. After changing the size of the browser, the font seems to be uploaded and everything is displayed. The problem is noticed only in one browser, the rest on the basis of WebKit/Blink is also possible.

I redo this bug only once, after the page was reloaded, everything became normal. So the bug could not be caught and fixed. What is the problem, how to solve it?

I used several solutions, but it didn`t help. For example it's to load the font after loading the main page, via JavaScript, on the onLoad event. And to do animation in 1ms after loading the page, that the browser would redraw the font (below is an example of the last fix).

```css
body {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fontfix {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```